# Add custom field for menu

Tags: 7, entities, routes

I am having menu like this in drupal which i have used superfish to show
[image: My Existing Menu]

I want each main menu to have a sub-title or description like this in below image
[image]

I searched alot online. Also tried for modules. Was wondering if there is a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the 'not often used' description field already available on each link? Then just add it into the menu links yourself on the front end by overriding the menu_link theme function.

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $description = '<span>' . $element['#localized_options']['#original_link']['description'] . '</span>';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'] . $description, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```